# Unable to push commits in git repository

Tags: node.js, git

I have made changes to my file and now would like to push those commits. I tried using
`git commit` and it is giving me Error

```sh
$ git commit
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

**What I've Tried**

1. I have tried deleting node modules and installing them again but that didnt solve the problem.
2. Working on other repositories

> Node version - 16.14.0
> npm version - 8.5.0

I tried searching everywhere but was unable to find any workable solution. I am not sure what is causing this error

Comment: OS? What shell?

Comment: `git commit` won't give that error at all. `npm` would, and if you're running `npm` from a *hook* (such as a pre-commit hook), that would explain it. So: what Git hooks are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the .git/hooks directory exists in your project directory. you can try deleting the .git/hooks directory

Comment: I had a similar situation+error and deleting the .git/hooks folder (and letting git recreate it) worked! Thanks!!